# Jquery removing default text from textbox on submit

Tags: jquery

```
     $('input[class*="defaulttext"]').each(function () {

                    this.value = $(this).attr('title');
                    $(this).addClass('defaultclass');

                    $(this).focus(function () {
                        if (this.value == $(this).attr('title')) {
                            this.value = '';
                            $(this).removeClass('defaultclass');
                        }
                    });

                    $(this).blur(function () {
                    if (this.value == '') {
                        this.value = $(this).attr('title');
                        $(this).addClass('defaultclass');
                    }
                });


                });
```

This basically adds the background text effect for textboxes (uses the title). Once selected the text goes away.

Now, I have a problem with optional fields. If the user does not edit these fields the default background text is submitted with the form. So I need to reset the value of the unedited field once the form is submitted. Any ideas how to do this?

Maybe on form submit, check if the title = value? If yes then set to ''.

Comment: You're not adding "background text", you're actually setting the value of the field. Why not use the HTML5 [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute?

Comment: j08691 - good suggestion,but you also have to remember most users do not use modern browsers that will support it.

Comment: Wasn't familiar with the placeholder attribute. Will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you have, you could do:

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function () {
     $('input[class*="defaulttext"]').val("");
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't this empty all the inputs, including the ones that has been filled?

Comment: Nah because in his `blur` function he's adding and removing the default class if it has a value.

Answer (score 1):

We used [HTML5 Placeholder jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) and it worked well in this case.

Comment: For compliant browsers, this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, and check for values where title=value. Or alternatively, you could mark your edited fields using [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function () {
    $('input.defaulttext').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() === $(this).attr('title')) { $(this).val(''); }
    });
};
```